# Не работает sys.exit()

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста исправить скрипт

```
import tkinter
import sys

def yesNo(title, message):
    if tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title, message):
        result = True
    else:
        result = False

    return result

if yesNo("Exit", "Do you want to quit?"):
    print('t')
    sys.exit()
else:
    print('f')

input()
```

после запуска из среды IDLE и нажатия кнопки в диалоге askyesno в консоль выводится "t" или "f". при этом выхода из программы не происходит(то есть инструкция sys.exit() не выполняется)

если этот код запускать в windows7 из total commander двойным щелчком на имени файла, то на долю секунды показывается чёрный экран консоли и закрывается.

Answer (score 1):

```
root.destroy()
```

**Upd.**

А если так:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
...
if messagebox.askyesno(title, message):
...
```

Comment: дык нету рута то. сам бы рад...

Comment: Попробуй из консоли скрипт запустить, посмотреть что именно пишет.